# JQuery Mobile scrollview fit to screen height

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I want `scrollview` in `JQuery Mobile` to fit on the screen height.

I want three rows of items, and height of the items should be changed automatically when page resizes.

this is my `scrollview container` css code:

```
    .threeByThree {
        border: solid 0px black;
        background-color: #ccc;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80%;
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-left:10px;
    }
```

and this is the css code of elements inside `scrollview`:

```
    .square {
        width: 200px;
        height: 30%;
        border: solid 0px #333;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    }
```

Also page and content elements are this css code : `height:100%`.

my complete page code is [here](http://pastie.org/4171015).

But it don't work correctly. When I change the height of the browser (by resizing browser), sometimes a scrollbar appears, and elements are not resized correctly...

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using scrollview, which is no longer supported by Jquery Mobile. Try any of the following:

[Overthrow](http://filamentgroup.github.com/Overthrow/) - supposed to be the follow up to Scrollview
  [JQM iscrollview](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) - another alternative

Comment: Thanks! But please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262644/horizontal-scrolling-with-mouse-wheel-with-overthrow-plugin