# Horizontal scrolling with mouse wheel with Overthrow plugin

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using [overthrow](http://filamentgroup.github.com/Overthrow/) plugin for horizontal scrolling in both desktop and mobile platforms.

[This](http://pastie.org/4171373) is my code, it works correctly, but I want to allow scrolling on it **also by mouse wheel.**

How to do that?

Comment: try. this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842041/jquery-horizontal-scroll-with-mousewheel

Comment: In the function that used in that links, delta is always `undefined`...

Comment: sorry, haven't looked into this in detail, but there seem to be plenty of plugins available to link scroll events to the mousewheel scrolling. keep in mind that overflow scrolling doesn't necessarily trigger 'real' scroll events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that Mouse Wheel Plugin can solve the problem.

[Here is the solution.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/)