# Creating a grid layout with css

Tags: html, css

I'm going to create a horizontal grid layout with CSS. (And I'll make it to scroll horizontally by JQuery and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262644/horizontal-scrolling-with-mouse-wheel-with-overthrow-plugin) solution. Please note that scrolling is not my problem. my problem is about creating the grid)

This is an example:
[image]

I have searched the internet about CSS Grids, but it seems that they can't help me...

**My Question is, how to create something like the image above? Which plugins, or css properties should I use for this purpose?**

EDIT: I want to have fixed number of rows (I mean, the number of rows should **not** change when I resize the page. **there should be an scrollbar instead.**) (I will use it inside a div with `overflow: auto`)

Comment: Don't get angry now, but what kind of data are you going to display in the grid? Tabular data?

Comment: @MrLister each field contains a summary of an article.

Comment: No worries Mahdi - glad you got an answer useful to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`display:table`, `display:table-row`, `display:table-cell`, `display:inline-block`

These css properties can help, just look them up on your local css information site.

The `table`-values let every element behave like a table, without actually using one. This may be a good solution for your problem.

The `inline-block`-value solves the overhang problem some floating layouts have as the blocks are displayed *inline*, just like `img`s. There is little support for this in old browsers, of course.

Comment: What is wrong with this? http://jsfiddle.net/ZUNxD/1/ It changes the size of divs to fit on the page, but I don't want that... Also `margin` don't work...

Comment: A table tries to fit into all available width. You can force a bigger size with the `width` property; in your fiddle, set it in the `.a` class.

Comment: negative magins? Work, but the idea is horrible. Does `width: trazillion px !important;` not work? Do you have a current fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you said. are you saying that I should use negative margins?!?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. the `width` property should do the trick. Please, never use negative margins, except for menus. Is your table scrollable by now? Can I help you any further?

Comment: My table is scrollable. but `margin` of cells is not working. see my code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUNxD/3/

Comment: Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/mqXXa/18/ Essentially I added the `border-collapse` and `border-spacing` attributes. As our grid is told to behave like a table, we also have to style it accordingly. We can emulate a spacing between rows if we add an inner `div` as I did in row 1, cell 4.